# How to align ion-label to right?

Tags: ionic2

I am working on Ionic v2 and and facing issue in aligning ion-label value to the right. Following is the code snippet:

Html Code:

```html
<ion-content padding class="home">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item class="clearme">
            <ion-label>Employee Name:</ion-label>
            <ion-label class="alignme">Gaurav</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

CSS:

```css
.home {
    background-color: red;
}
    
.alignme {
    float:right !important;
}

.clearme {
    clear: both !important;
}
```

After adding these classes text is not getting aligned to right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use text-align instead of float.

```css
.alignme {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Btw you should use ion-label only with forms - ion-input, ion-checkbox etc.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with using `ion-label` inside `ion-item`. check ionic documentation [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item)

Answer (score 18):

You can also use `text-right` attribute directive like below.

```html
<ion-label text-right>Gaurav</ion-label>
```

For detail information about attribute directives, see [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html)

**Edit for Ionic 5**

```html
<ion-label class="ion-text-right">...</ion-label>
```

Comment: Agreed. Is it even a thing for correct answers to be changed on SO?

Answer (score 3):

Ionic has a built-in solution for this:

[Documenation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities#text-modification)

- Version 2-3:

```
    <ion-label ion-text-center>
       Centered text
    </ion-label>
```

- Version 4+:

```
    <ion-label class="ion-text-center">
       Centered text
    </ion-label>
```

Comment: For Ionic 4+, here is the documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities#text-alignment

Answer (score 0):

If still not success try this

```
 //html
 <ion-item>
  <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Username"></ion-input>
    <ion-label class="alignme">
        <ion-icon name="logo-playstation"></ion-icon>                     
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>

//css
    .alignme{

        position:absolute;
        right:0 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in ionic 5 this worked for me.

```html
<ion-item>
    <ion-label slot="start">Left Side</ion-label>
    <ion-label slot="end">Right Side</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```