# How can I set prefix value in ionic text field in <ion-input>?

Tags: android, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

Currently I am getting the data from the user( in this case here, it's mobile number). Here currently I have declared in such a way that if we tap the `<ion-input>` it will automatically add "+27" But currently it's editable(i.e, We can delete the +27).

But I don't want it to be get deleted? tried several methods but none worked out. I have also tried to set this "+27" read-only in one `<ion-input>` and other input to enter the mobile number. But it's resulting in collapsing the UI (i.e, this mobile number field gets hidden somewhere else).

Here's what I have tried:

My html:

```
<ion-item>
                        <ion-icon name="md-phone-portrait" class="iconstyle" item-start></ion-icon>
                        <ion-label color="iconcolor" floating>Mobile Number</ion-label>
                        <ion-input no-border class="mydate" type="tel" [(ngModel)]="vm.mobileNumber" minlength="12" maxlength="12" (tap)="mobilecode()"
                                   formControlName="mobile" tabindex="1" (keyup)="moveFocus($event,password, false)"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>
```

My ts file:

```
public changeMobile() {
        if (this.vm.mobileNumber.length == 0)
            this.vm.mobileNumber = "+27"

    }
```

What I need is that I don't want the country code to be get deleted even if the user press the backspace key.

Comment: something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44341564/ionic2-input-label-fixed-on-the-right-of-ion-input-field ?

Comment: @SurajRao thanks will check nd let you know

Comment: @SurajRao it's going down of the textfield line

Comment: @SurajRao.. OK when I removed the order, It's above the text line., but not on the text line